# Move heading 1 and heading 2 to the right of image

Tags: html, css

I want to have `<h1>` and `<h2>` to the right of an image but `<h2>` must be under `<h1>`. How do I go about this?

**My Code**

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<img src="images/SelzerSeal.jpg" alt="Henry Selzer attorney at law">
<h1>Test</h1><br>
<h2>Test 2</h2>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
img {
max-width: 100%;
text-align: center;
float:left;
}
h1{
color:white;
font-size: 24px;
float:left;
font-family:"Book Antiqua";
}
h2 {
color:white;
font-size:20px;
float:left; 
font-family:"Times New Roman";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add float to either h1 or h2

[See demo](https://jsfiddle.net/th82cjny/)

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<img src="images/SelzerSeal.jpg" alt="Henry Selzer attorney at law">
<h1>Test</h1>
<h2>Test 2</h2>
</html>

img {
max-width: 100%;
float:left;
margin-right: 1%}
h1{
color:white;
font-size: 24px;
font-family:"Book Antiqua";
}
h2 {
color:white;
font-size:20px;
font-family:"Times New Roman";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try getting rid of `float: left;` property on both header tags, also get rid of the `<br>` tag in html, and the div with class "clear" is not necessary.

Here is an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/t769avo2/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```css
.img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="" class="img">
<h1>Header H1</h1>
<h2>Header H2</h2>
```

I hope I helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `floats` from your heading tags:

```css
body {
  background:#000;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  float:left;
}
h1{
  color:white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family:"Book Antiqua";
}
h2 {
  color:white;
  font-size:20px;
  font-family:"Times New Roman";
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Henry Selzer attorney at law">
<h1>Test</h1><br>
<h2>Test 2</h2>
```